# Implicit parameter modifiers with delegates? (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm working on a library that allows users to instantiate some delegates.

I have a defined a delegate type that deals with a struct as one of its parameters, that we only need to read and not modify, so the `in` keyword seemed useful.

```cs
public struct SomeStruct 
{ 
    public string x; 
    // and possibly more...
}

public delegate void MyDelegate(object foo, in SomeStruct bar);
```

However, when I go to create it, it tells me I need to put `in` there.

```cs
// Parameter 2 must be declared with the 'in' keyword
MyDelegate x = (foo, bar) => System.Console.WriteLine(bar.x);
```

If I use `in`, I now have to explicitly type the parameter...

```cs
// doesn't work
MyDelegate x = (foo, in bar) => System.Console.WriteLine(bar.x);
```

But now that I explicitly type the second parameter, the first parameter needs to be explicit too.

```cs
// Inconsistent lambda parameter usage; parameter types must be all explicit or all implicit
MyDelegate x = (foo, in SomeStruct bar) => System.Console.WriteLine(bar.x);
```

```cs
// ok
MyDelegate x = (object foo, in SomeStruct bar) => System.Console.WriteLine(bar.x);
```

Now in my use case, the types for parameters `foo` and `bar` could have long names, generic parameters, etc.

The type information is already there where this delegate type is defined. Is there a way to avoid making my users explicitly type the parameters for this delegate?

I expected `(foo, bar) =>` or `(foo, in bar) =>` to work but it does not.

edit: I was playing around more and this seems to be the case for `ref` as well, I'm guessing for all parameter modifiers. So question name was changed from just asking about `in` to modifiers in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't provide modifiers with implicit anonymous function parameters.

If you look at the [grammar in the ECMA standard](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v6/standard/expressions.md#12161-general) - which is currently for C# 6, hence the lack of the `in` modifier - you'll see the difference between `explicit_anonymous_function_parameter` which includes both an optional modifier and a type, and an `implicit_anonymous_function_parameter` which is *just* an identifier:

```
explicit_anonymous_function_parameter
    : anonymous_function_parameter_modifier? type Identifier
    ;

anonymous_function_parameter_modifier
    : 'ref'
    | 'out'
    ;

implicit_anonymous_function_parameter
    : Identifier
    ;
```

I agree this can be slightly frustrating - but I wouldn't *expect* to see it change any time soon.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's a real shame, as it makes the kind of API I was playing around with prohibitively inconvenient to use :/ Is there any way I can check if this has been raised or talked about with the team?

Comment: @James: You can raise it on https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang